# Responsive Images with art direction

Tags: theme-development, images, responsive

I've been thinking about how I would use responsive images in Wordpress. My site has a fixed height, full width thumbnail at the top of each post. The built in Wordpress implementation of responsive images assumes a constant aspect ratio, which this use-case doesn't have.

I've created 6 image size, covering 3 widths and 2x pixels:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'setup_image_sizes' );
function setup_image_sizes() {
  $height = 150;
  $width  = 250;
  $gutter = 50;

  add_image_size( 'single-width', $width, $height, true ); //Single width Thumbnail
  add_image_size( 'single-width-2x', $width * 2, $height * 2, true ); //Single width Thumbnail
  add_image_size( 'double-width', 2 * $width + $gutter, $height, true ); //Double width Thumbnail
  add_image_size( 'double-width-2x', ( 2 * $width + $gutter ) * 2, $height * 2, true ); //Double width Thumbnail
  add_image_size( 'triple-width', 3 * $width + 2 * $gutter, $height, true ); //Triple width Thumbnail
  add_image_size( 'triple-width-2x', ( 3 * $width + 2 * $gutter ) * 2, $height * 2, true ); //Triple width Thumbnail
}
```

Having done this, I have no idea how I would build a `<picture>` element. Any help  and guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The 'picture' element supports `min-width` and `max-width`.

If the image is a `featured image` then `wp_get_attachment_image_src` is what you would use:

```
// open the picture element
<picture>

// use this image if the width of a screen does not go over 599px
<source srcset="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'whatever add_image_size you want to use', false )[0] ?>" media="(max-width: 599px)">

// call an image
<source srcset="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'whatever add_image_size you want to use', false )[0] ?>">

// fall back for older browsers
<img srcset="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'whatever add_image_size you want to use', false )[0] ?>">

// close the picture element
</picture>
```

You can have as many as you want